# how to make the changes of element done by java script permanent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my question is how can i  make the changes of element done by java script in web-browser permanent.

i wrote a code in html by using this html code i can change the size as well as position of the html element as you can see in this gif

---

[image]

---

as i changed the position and size of html element so is it possible to make the new position and size of that html element permanent and how can i do it ?

here is my code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>header div element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">move</div>
  <p>drag</p>
  <p>to</p>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

By "permanent" i mean it will keep its position when you reload the page

Comment: You'd need to store the data like position, size, etc. somewhere like a cookie, localstorage, a database, so that it could be read back in later.

Comment: By "permanent" do you mean it will keep its position when you reload the page, or do you mean you want to lock the element and prevent future changes?

Comment: @Joe_Frambach  By "permanent" i mean it will keep its position when you reload the page

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because there is little research effort. If I search for your *exact* title, limited to just StackOverflow.com, I get [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+the+changes+of+element+done+by+java+script+permanent+site%3Astackoverflow.com), which includes several Q&A which would have helped you out if you would just have done that simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is save the position of the element in your user's browser. This is usually done by using cookies, or HTML5's localStorage.

To utilize either technology for your problem, you simply create a function that receives 2 parameters for the position of you element, and save these params in either localStorage or a cookie. Then, when you use dragElement(e) on a element, you first try to get the x and y from the localStorage object. If they are there, the element is positioned where it was before.

That's just for the position.
If you also want to save the size of the element, you just need to save a third parameter that gets changed whenever you resize the element. Possibly the easiest way to detect whether or not an element's size has changed is a solution by LegoMushroom (https://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/FnizC). What this does is it adds an event called "onresize" that can be attached to any element.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  // get position from localstorage if there is any
  try {
    let x = window.localStorage.getItem("x");
    let y = window.localStorage.getItem("y");
    positionElement(x,y);
    let w = window.localStorage.getItem("w");
    resizeElement(w);
  }catch(e){
    e.message != "The operation is insecure." && console.log("X, Y or W not set in LocalStorage",e);
  }
  
  elmnt.addEventListener('onresize', () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("w", elmnt.style.width);
    resizeElement(elmnt.style.width);
  });
  
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    positionElement(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
  
  function positionElement(x, y) {
    pos1 = pos3 - x;
    pos2 = pos4 - y;
    pos3 = x;
    pos4 = y;
    
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    // set localStorage x and y
    window.localStorage.setItem("x", x);
    window.localStorage.setItem("y", y);
  }
  
  function resizeElement(w) {
    elmnt.style.width = w;
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://sk-cdn.net/libraries/jsresize/min.js"></script>

<h1>header div element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">move</div>
  <p>drag</p>
  <p>to</p>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

There are still some bugs with the positioning and it doesn't really work in the snippet here (some permissions error), I'll get to fixing those later, you may try your luck yourself!